# Athena query is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am storing 400,000 parquet files in S3 that are partitioned based on a unique id (e.g. 412812). The files range in size from 25kb to 250kb of data. I then want to query the data using Athena. Like so,

```
Select * 
From Table 
where id in (412812, 412813, 412814)
```

This query is much slower than anticipated. I want to be able to search for any set of ids and get a fast response. I believe it is slow is because Athena must search through the entire glue catalog looking for the right file (i.e., a full scan of files).

The following query is extremely fast. Less than a second.

```
Select * 
From Table 
where id = 412812
```

partition.filtering is enabled on the table. I tried adding an index to the table that was the same as the partition, but it did not speed anything up.

Is there something wrong with my approach or a table configuration that would make this process faster?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/ - starting off: your files are far too small. What index are you talking about? is the data actually partitioned? The second query really cannot be faster than the first query because they need to do the exact same thing. In general athena is (very) slow compared to a normal database because it does not have any (smart) indexing.

Comment: @luk2302 The data is partitioned by "id". I then tried to add a partition index to the table via AWS Glue. According to glue docs: "Indexes on Numeric and String data types support =, >, >=, <= and between operators. The indexing solution currently only supports the AND logical operator. Sub-expressions with the operators "LIKE", "IN", "OR", and "NOT" are ignored in the expression for filtering using an index. Filtering for the ignored subexpression is done on the partitions fetched after applying index filtering." So, my assumption is the queries are not the same.

Comment: That is really messed up :facepalm: And you are talking partitioning like some_prefix/id=123/file.ending , right?

Comment: How many files are being stored in each sub-directory as a partition? Can you tell us why you have so many separate parquet files? Would it be okay if you merged them into a smaller number of files?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the structure is bucket/partitions/id=412812/file.snappy.parquet. There are 400k partitions and one parquet for each partition. The reason for this storage and this many unique files is flexibility. I want to be able to combine any combination of partitions based on id and build the same workflow with those ids. If I merge the files, my assumption was that looking up by "id" would no longer be quick. Currently, it's much faster to pass the paths to wrangler s3 read parquet than using athena.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your basic problem is that **you have too many files and too many partitions**.

While Amazon Athena does operate in parallel, there are limits to how many files it can process simultaneously. Plus, each extra file adds overhead for listing, opening, etc.

Also, putting just a single file in each partition greatly adds to the overhead of handling so many partitions and is probably counterproductive for increasing the efficiency of the system.

I have no idea of how you actually use your data, but based on your description I would recommend that you **create a new table that is `bucketed_by` the id, rather than partitioned:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
 format = 'PARQUET',
 parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
 external_location = 's3://bucket/new_location/',
 bucketed_by = ARRAY['id']
)
AS SELECT * FROM existing_table
```

Let Athena create as many files as it likes -- it will optimize based upon the amount of data. More importantly, it will create larger files that allow it to operate more efficiently.

See: [Bucketing vs Partitioning - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html)

In general, **partitions** are great when you can divide the data into some major subsets (eg by country, state or something that represents a sizeable chunk of your data), while **bucketing** is better for fields that have values that are relatively uncommon (eg user IDs). Bucketing will create multiple files and Athena will be smart enough to know which files contain the IDs you want. However, it will not be partitioned into subdirectories based upon those values.

Creating this new table will greatly reduce the number of files that Amazon Athena would need to process for each query, which will **make your queries run a *LOT* faster**.

Comment: Thanks for this answer John! this helped me a lot.
If I want to insert new data into a bucketed table, do you have any idea how should I set it up? I'm creating the table schemas using AWS glue crawlers.

Comment: @EyalCohen If the data is being inserted through `INSERT INTO` commands, then Athena will take care of creating the storage files in the right location. If you are adding data yourself by storing files in S3, I'm not sure how that would impact bucketing.